# With VIM, use both snipMate and pydiction together (share the <tab> key?)

Tags: vim, autocomplete, code-snippets

I am trying to use [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) and [pydiction](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) in vim together - however, both use the `<tab>` key to perform their genius-auto-completion-snippet-rendering-goodness-that-I-so-desire.

When pydiction is installed, snipMate stops working.  I assume its because they can't both own the `<tab>` key.  How can I get them to work together?

I wouldn't mind mapping one of them to a different key, but I am not really sure how to do this ... (maybe pydiction to the `<ctrl-n>` key so it mimics vim's autocomplete?).

Here is the relevant .vimrc:

```
filetype indent plugin on 

autocmd FileType python set ft=python.django 
autocmd FileType html set ft=html.django_template 

let g:pydiction_location = '~/.vim/ftplugin/pydiction-1.2/complete-dict'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, this is from the Snipmate help file :)

```
                                                              *snipMate-remap*
snipMate does not come with a setting to customize the trigger key, but you
can remap it easily in the two lines it's defined in the 'after' directory
under 'plugin/snipMate.vim'. For instance, to change the trigger key
to CTRL-J, just change this: >

 ino <tab> <c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
 snor <tab> <esc>i<right><c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>

to this: >
 ino <c-j> <c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
 snor <c-j> <esc>i<right><c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks!  Perhaps in all my searching I should have looked more closely at the help docs.  Heh.

Comment: No longer true, now the documentation specifies that it can be remapped with `imap <C-J> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger` and `smap <C-J> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger`

Comment: +1 @TKrugg See my dotfiles commit with the remaps. https://github.com/simeonwillbanks/dotfiles/commit/660b0505c82157656e15d47cd43108d2d39409db

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can edit `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python_pydiction.vim`
and change `Tab` to something else:

```
" Make the Tab key do python code completion:
inoremap <silent> <buffer> <Tab> 
         \<C-R>=<SID>SetVals()<CR>
         \<C-R>=<SID>TabComplete('down')<CR>
         \<C-R>=<SID>RestoreVals()<CR>

" Make Shift+Tab do python code completion in the reverse direction:
inoremap <silent> <buffer> <S-Tab> 
         \<C-R>=<SID>SetVals()<CR>
         \<C-R>=<SID>TabComplete('up')<CR>
         \<C-R>=<SID>RestoreVals()<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the way to change the trigger key may have changed since the answer by the_karel was given in 2009 but it is found in the same directory, namely 'after/plugin/snipMate.vim'. I found it in the help file too:

```
 *snipMate-trigger*
snipMate comes with a setting to configure the key that is used to trigger
snipMate. To configure the key set g:snips_trigger_key to something other than
<tab>,e.g. <c-space> use:

 let g:snips_trigger_key='<c-space>'
```